# Async function support in Mithril.js for webpack dynamic imports?

Tags: mithril.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use dynamic import in webpack with mithril. To do that elegantly, I think I'll need to use an async function somewhere along the line. Right now this is how I have used the async function:

```
import m from 'mithril'

let App = async () => {
  let { Component } = await import('./components.js')
  return {
    view () {
      return m(Component)
    }
  }
}

App().then(app => m.mount(document.body, app))
```

Ideally, I want to use it like this:

```
import m from 'mithril'

let App = {
    async view () {
      let { Component } = await import('./components.js')
      return m(Component)
    }
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, App)
```

Is there something I've been missing from the documentation to acheive what I'd like to do? I've tried to look at every mention of promise, but it's possible that I've missed this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/issues/468 has an answer to this, it links to this code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kYUA1JinUcwlnrNK8ltG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One way that should work is this:

```
async function main() {
    const myModule = await import('./myModule.js');

    const {export1, export2} = await import('./myModule.js');

    const [module1, module2, module3] =
        await Promise.all([
            import('./module1.js'),
            import('./module2.js'),
            import('./module3.js'),
        ]);
}
main();

(async () => {
    const myModule = await import('./myModule.js');
})();
```

For further information follow the link below.

[ES proposal: import() – dynamically importing ES modules](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which provides a simple component named **DynamicComponent** which can be used anywhere and with children:

**App.js**

```es6
import m from 'mithril'
import { DynamicComponent } from './DynamicComponent'

const App = {
    view() {
      return m( DynamicComponent, {
        component: 'OtherComponent'
      }, 'Hello world' ),
    }
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, App)
```

**OtherComponent.js**

```es6
import m from 'mithril'

export function OtherComponent() { return {
  view({ children }) { return m( 'div', children )}
}}
```

**DynamicComponent.js**

```es6
import { hooks } from '/hooks'

export function DynamicComponent() { return {
  ...hooks,
  attrs: null,
  component: null,

  view({ children }) { return (
    // Await module resolution and process attributes.
    // Use '&&' as a shortcut to only continue 
    // once 'this.component' isn't null.
    // Pass a clone of attrs to the loaded component. 
    this.component && m( this.component.default, this.attrs, children )
  )}
}}
```

**hooks.js**

```es6
async function oninit({ attrs }) {
  // Preload -> Load immediately, in parallel
  // Prefetch -> Load when browser is idle (Can be less responsive)
  // See more: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetching-preloading-modules
  // Dynamically import component and append '.js' (Don't include '.js' in your imports).
  if ( attrs.loadType = 'prefetch' ) {
    // Lazy load
    this.component = await import( /* webpackPrefetch: true */ `
      ${ attrs.component }.js`
    )
  } else {
    // Immediate load
    this.component = await import( /* webpackPreload: true */ `
      ${ attrs.component }.js`
    )
  }

  /*
    Process and pass along attributes
    This clones the attributes to prevent any changes from affecting
    the original attributes.

    You can save memory if it becomes a problem by directly
    assigning `v.attrs` to `newAttrs`, but you lose this immutability.
  */
  const newAttrs = { ...v.attrs }

  // Remove attributes used in `DynamicComponent`
  delete newAttrs.component
  delete newAttrs.loadType

  // Assign to component
  this.attrs = newAttrs

  m.redraw()
}


export const hooks = {
  oninit,
}
```